# error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *const' with an rvalue of type 'const int *

Tags: c++, pointers, constexpr

Why am I getting this error: `error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *const'
      with an rvalue of type 'const int *` when compiling the following code?
Code:

```
constexpr int ch1 = 5;
constexpr int* pch1 = &ch1;
constexpr int ch2 = 5;
constexpr int* pch2 = &ch2;

cout << *pch1+*pch2;
```

Let me make this clear. The point of this whole ordeal is to initialise these variables at compile time. If there's a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: A mutable pointer to a constant integer is not the same as a constant pointer to a mutable integer.  `constexpr` makes the pointer const, but not the pointed-to thing; you have to use `constexpr const int*` or `constexpr int const*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have declared `pch1` and `pch2` as `constexpr` does not of itself make them `const int *`, so you would need:

```
constexpr int ch1 = 5;
constexpr const int* pch1 = &ch1;
constexpr int ch2 = 5;
constexpr const int* pch2 = &ch2;
```

However, then you get:

```
error: '& ch1' is not a constant expression
error: '& ch2' is not a constant expression
```

So you're still not winning.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/28FYIBCwrsGIRQG4)

---

**Edit:** As chris points out, you can fix the latter problem by declaring `ch1` and `ch2` as `static`.  Their addresses then become `constexpr`:

```
constexpr static int ch1 = 5;
constexpr const int* pch1 = &ch1;
constexpr static int ch2 = 5;
constexpr const int* pch2 = &ch2;
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QVE13BN1c1iFSoFQ)

Comment: You can always give the ints static storage duration.